# File not found error in Android

Tags: android

I have two folders inside my assets folder which contains 3 html files. I am loading one of this HTML file in a webview and inside this file I am referring other two files using href. When I run this code and click on this link inside the webview I am getting an error in the webview that It cannot find the file. How should I give the path of the file. I am just giving the file name only because it  is in the same path as the referring HTML file.
What am I doing wrong?

This is inside my html file.

> ```
> Functions <a href="android.resource://com.com.com/assets/begin.html">begin()</a>
> ```

```
<a href="android.resource://com.mypack.test/assets/begin.html">begin()</a>

<a href="file:///android_asset/begin.html">begin()</a>
```

I tried both didn't work

I am trying to get the begin.html file.

This is my java code

```
 WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        String str = readFile(parent_folder +"/"+ folder_name);
        web.loadData(str, "text/html", null);
```

readFile() reads the HTML file and returns the contents.

inside this webview I am linking to another html file inside the assets folder.

Comment: write the path name that you are mentioning to load the page...

Comment: mention the path of the file you use

Comment: you are saying I should use folder1/folder2/myfile.html. I tried it but same error.

Comment: Please upload your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
android.resource://com.com.com/assets/file
```

use the above file path as uri to load the file if you have no folders in asset folder.
Better if you keep the files in raw folder and use it as

```
android.resource://com.com.com/raw/filename
```

**Note::** com.com.com is your package name

Refer this [LINK](http://android-pro.blogspot.in/2010/01/understanding-assets.html) for usage of file from assets folder

Updated::

```
   WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
   Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.com.com/raw/filename");
   web.loadUrl(path);//may need to convert uri to string
```

Comment: what is this com.com.com? is that my package name?

Comment: This "<a href="file:///android_asset/begin.html">begin()</a>" is the code inside my html file in the webview

Comment: Please anyone help me on this. I am stuck on this.

Comment: Hello Agarwal, Actually I dont want to so anything in the java file. Just want to load an html file from another HTML file's href which is initially loaded in the webview.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/begin.html">
```